# wordpress tinyMCE linebreak

Tags: php, editor, tinymce, shortcode

I'm developing a plugin for running multilingual websites where I'm using a shortcode [translate lang=en] for each language in the tinyMCE editor, I'm using a function that inserts a div around each language tag in the editor screen, and using editor-style.css to make a border around that div to separate each language from the other.

When I hit enter for a new line, tinyMCE automatically creates a new div around the new line.

what i'm getting when I hit enter:

```
[translate lang=en]
<div class="lang_editor_divider">line 1</div>
<div class="lang_editor_divider">line 2</div>
[/translate]
```

what i'm trying to get:

```
[translate lang=en]
<div class="lang_editor_divider">line 1
line 2</div>
[/translate]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinymce is a real-time-editor which creates html code as output.
In order to style the html and do other stuff it is necessary to wrap the written text into html-tags (usually p-tags or div-tags). Tinymce takes care of that.

In order to achieve what you desire you would need to catch the enter-keydown event and prevent the further propagation, which i do not advise.